# Get scroll position and extent for a Webview

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I have a Webview control in my Mac OS X application UI and I need to somehow determine whether the content in the control can be scrolled or not. In other words, is the scroll position at the end of the control?

With some experiment, I'm finding that the following works just *some* of the time:

```
-(BOOL)canScroll
{
    NSScroller * scroll = self.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.enclosingScrollView.verticalScroller;
    return scroll.knobProportion > 0.0 && scroll.knobProportion < 1.0 && scroll.floatValue < 1.0;
}
```

However a lot of the time it doesn't. I've not been able to determine the circumstances in which it should work and the documentation on the web is vague. Can somebody recommend a reliable way to determine if the Webview can scroll WITHOUT actually performing the scroll and comparing the visible content area?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something similar and started experimenting with the presence of the scroller yes or no. This lead to this method although I have to warn that this is purely empirically defined.

```
func canScroll() -> Bool {
    guard let scroll = self.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.enclosingScrollView?.verticalScroller else { return false }
    let knobProportion = scroll.knobProportion
    let floatValue = scroll.floatValue
    if scroll.usableParts == .noScrollerParts {
        return floatValue < 1.0 && floatValue != 0.0
    } else {
        return knobProportion > 0.0 && knobProportion < 1.0 && floatValue < 1.0
    }
}
```

This seems to work reliably so far.